# How do I manage multiple processes in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple (i hope) question:
my problems started when i wrote a GUI.
i cannot refresh the user interface while executing heavy computations.

-if i use threads there is the G.I.L. (not too slow but the gui freezes)

i tryed so many things that my last hope is starting a new process (and here the problem)

first of all:
-i never used processes before (it could be a semantic error)

-i don't know the limitations ( and exceptions ) of processes

-i am running with cpython 3.1.2 , on Mac os x v 10.6.8

here is an example (not the real code but the result is the same) of what i need to solve:

```
from multiprocessing import *
def bob(q):
    print(q)
A=Process(target=bob,args=("something"))
A.start()
A.is_alive()
A.join()
```

and the output is:

```
True
```

it doesn't print "something",so i guess it doesn't run the process,but "A.is_alive()" says it is running and when the interpreter arrives to "A.join()" it waits more or less forever

can someone explain me this?

Comment: Welcome to [su]! This looks like it's a programming question, so it's probably going to get moved over to our sister site at [so] which focuses specifically on programming questions.

Comment: oh sorry , i was on that site some minutes before posting the question , that is a my mistake , how can i see where will it be moved?  Alberto

Comment: Once the move happens, there will be a link here saying "Moved to Stack Overflow" that you can click on, and anyone finding it in [su]'s search will be automatically redirected. It takes 5 close votes, and at current time of writing it's at 3. Good luck finding your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should give a list of arguments, not just the argument. This does the job for me:

```
from multiprocessing import *
def bob(q):
    print(q)
A=Process(target=bob,args=["something"])
A.start()
A.is_alive()
A.join()
```

The following using sleep-sort (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474318/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-sleep-sort) to sort upper case characters A-Z

```
somestring="DGAECBF"
from multiprocessing import *
def bob(t):
    import time
    time.sleep(ord(t)-ord("A"))
    print(t)
p=[]
for c in somestring : 
    p.append(Process(target=bob,args=([c])))
    p[-1].start()
for pp in p:
    pp.join()
```

Comment: there is no need to use `()` around `[]`. It is identical to `args=["something"]`. btw, you could simplify sleepsort by using a [mp.Pool](https://gist.github.com/eecc1456d369665f1ee4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add comma: `args=("something",)`.

Comma creates a tuple otherwise it is just a string in parentheses.