# Changing bash script countdown delay in 5 sec steps

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have following command i use in a script as a countdown timer and it works great

```
#  30 sec Countdown Timer
for i in {30..1};do echo -n "$i." && sleep 1; done

Output:30.29.28.27.26 etc....
```

But I would like to be able to output in 5sec intervals
like

```
: 30.25.20.15 etc..
```

how can i change the script to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for i in {30..1..5};do echo -n "$i." && sleep 5; done
```

Comment: I would have upvoted it immediately but it took me 30 seconds to test your code :)

Comment: @Tom Fenech: :) This reminds me of this: How do I calculate the date of tomorrow? `sleep $((60*60*24)); date`

Comment: :) And that reminded me of [sleepsort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474318/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-sleep-sort).

Comment: Note that this approach requires `bash` 4.0 or newer.  Could alternatively do `seq 30 -5 1`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: \*lol\* very nice. @JohnB: thank you for the hint. Alternatively do: `for ((i=30;i>0;i=i-5)); do echo -n "$i." && sleep 5; done`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in {30..1}
do 
  if [ $((i%5)) == 0 ]
  then 
    echo -n "$i."
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: your condition could be `if ((i%5 == 0))`

Comment: Of course, although it seems redundant to use `[` and `$(( ))` together in bash. If you _are_ going to use `[`, you should change `==` to `=` (or better yet, `-eq`), as `==` is not understood by other POSIX shells. If you did that, your version would be more portable than my suggestion, which is bash-specific.

Comment: If you _need_ the portability, use `[`, but otherwise _please_ use `[[` and your life will be easier. :) See [Conditional Blocks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals?#Conditional_Blocks) and [Bash Tests](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices?#Bash_Tests).

Answer (score 0):

Here is straightforward script compatible with Dash and Bash:

```
i=30 && while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do sleep 5; i=$(($i-5)); printf "$i."; done
```